# App apk not install on phone during Updation

Tags: android-studio, debugging, android-install-apk

I already Published my App on the Google Play Store. Then I added few features and updates. To check apk's new update I click on the *Run* Button in Android Studio 2.3 and selected my phone as preview, then click *okay* and it showed the error message below.

I have deleted and reserved all apks.1,apk.2 per the error shown in the image below but no apk install to test. Please help how to solve this error and install it as a test to check.

[image: error]

Comment: Did you update the version number in the manifest file?

Comment: No... The VersionCode and VersionName both in Manifesto and Gradle same. Where I MISSING @CedricMartens

Comment: Everytime you update your app, you must update the version code.

Comment: I have previous VersionCode is "1" and as per your advise I update in with "1.1" in Manifesto and Gradle , the Manifesto shown error i.e. "This VersionCode (1.1) is not in used.It is always overridden by the value specified in the Gradle build script(1) @CedricMartens

Comment: Version code is only an integer. It is not the same as the version name. Please do some research before posting on StackExchange